# Is Python script allowed in MySQL server?

Tags: mysql

I know it is possible to install a Python plugin in PostgreSQL to execute Python code natively.

Is it possible in MySQL server to execute native Python or C++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an api for python and Mysql as well as C++ and Mysql.

You will need the Mysql Connector/Python 2.0 but make sure that it is compatible with your version of Python since they have one for Pv2 and Pv3.

More information here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/

There is also a Mysql Connector/C++ 1.1

More information here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/index.html